# Iterate / Unpivot Nested JSON Array for Use In Google Sheets with Zapier

Tags: json, zapier

I have a double-nested Json Array. There is one array called "data_points". there are a total of 25 "data_points" arrays. Nested within each of the 25 "data_points" arrays are 20 unique arrays called "results".

I need the output file un-pivoted such that:

"data_point" is duplicated 1 time for each of the 20 "results"

The output file should have 500 rows, but even if I use the "line itemizer" feature, Zapier only gives me the first object from "result" for each "data_point" array item.

Expected output file example provided in photo

```
"keyword": "sports bars near me",
    "lat": "28.3907656",
    "lng": "-81.2438784",
    "grid_size": "5",
    "radius": "2",
    "measurement": "mi",
    "points": "25",
    "found_in": "0",
    "arp": "21.00",
    "atrp": "21.00",
    "solv": "0.00",
    "image": "https://****************",
    "pdf": "https:****************",
    "public_url": "https:***************",
    "data_points": [
      {
        "lat": "28.3618517",
        "lng": "-81.2767454",
        "found": false,
        "rank": "",
        "count": 20,
        "results": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "place_id": "*************",
            "name": "Skybox Sports Tavern",
            "address": "225 Simpson Rd, Kissimmee, FL 34744",
            "lat": "28.2888311",
            "lng": "-81.3535695",
            "rating": "4.500",
            "reviews": "192",
            "store_code": false,
            "categories": {
              "bar": "Bar"
            }
          },
          {
            "rank": 2,
            "place_id": "**************",
            "name": "Nona Social Bar & Kitchen",
            "address": "9145 Narcoossee Rd, Orlando, FL 32827",
            "lat": "28.4347131",
            "lng": "-81.2563982",
            "rating": "4.300",
            "reviews": "415",
            "store_code": false,
            "categories": {
              "bar": "Bar"
            }
          },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43nG1.png)

I've tried formatting with Zapier, and Power Automate's "Apply To Each" feature to force each data_point to be duplicated 25 times, but I get Frankenstein results.

I know there's a way to do this with code but I'm stumped on how to tell the code to duplicate each data_point array item per each result.

I was able to get the result using PowerQuery, but I need it automated in Zapier, or some other way, as I'm dealing with dozens of JSON feeds.